# Custom nginx configuration for Laravel in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Hi I am using AWS elastic beanstalk for my Laravel application

When I first uploaded my application it is not showing the login page, 404 error so I tried with app_url/index.php/login and it worked

This is how I figure out I need to add this to my Nginx configuration, I manually added this, ssh into ec2 instance, and worked

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

but every time I deploy my new code it replaces my manual code

I also read https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-proxy.html?icmpid=docs_elasticbeanstalk_console this doc and created this folder structure in my application root folder

```
.ebextensions
  nginx
    conf.d
      elasticbeanstalk
        my-server-conf.conf
```

Seems not working for me
Please let me know what should I put In my-server-conf.conf file and what should I do so it works for every deploy

Comment: How did it go? Is it still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `.platform`, not `.ebextensions` as explained in [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html). For example:

`.platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/laravel.conf`

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Comment: everything was right but the location of the file is wrong

it should be .platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/laravel.conf